# Chaining Dataframe function calls

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The following code does not work:

```
val newDF = df
          .withColumn("timestamp", when(df("processingDate").isNull, lit(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis))).otherwise(df("processingDate")))
          .withColumn("year", year(df("timestamp")))
          .withColumn("month", month(df("timestamp")))
          .withColumn("day", dayofmonth(df("timestamp")))
```

If I run it I will get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "timestamp" among ...
```

The problem is that although I have added "timestamp" as a column, it is not part of the original, immutable, "df".

Is there a way to refer to the previous Dataframe in the call chain?

I will update my code to the following so that it will work, but I am wondering if there is a better way.

```
val dfWithTimestamp = df.withColumn("timestamp", when(df("monBusinessDateTimestamp").isNull, lit(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis))).otherwise(df("monBusinessDateTimestamp")))

val newDF = dfWithTimestamp
          .withColumn("year", year(dfWithTimestamp("timestamp")))
          .withColumn("month", month(dfWithTimestamp("timestamp")))
          .withColumn("day", dayofmonth(dfWithTimestamp("timestamp")))
```

Comment: Can you share the schema of your Dataframe ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't check right now, but

```
val newDF = df
          .withColumn("timestamp", when(df("processingDate").isNull, lit(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis))).otherwise(df("processingDate")))
          .withColumn("year", year($"timestamp"))
          .withColumn("month", month($"timestamp"))
          .withColumn("day", dayofmonth($"timestamp"))
```

might work.

Comment: Pretty close, updated with a small correction.  Thanks for your help.