# Why does "groupBy agg count alias" not create a new column?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code:

```
def getResults(df: DataFrame) : Dataset[Row] = {
df.filter(df("srch_adults_cnt") > 0)
  .filter(df("srch_children_cnt") > 0)
  .filter(df("is_booking") === 0)
  .groupBy("hotel_country", "hotel_market", "hotel_continent")
  .agg(count("*").alias("count"))
  .orderBy(df("count").desc)
  .limit(3)
}
```

it failed on this line: `.orderBy(df("count").desc)`, saying that there's no such column `count`. Why is that?

when I replaced `df("count").desc` with `desc("count")` it started working, but I don't understand why. Can someone explain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chaining Dataframe function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34726740/10465355)

Answer (score 0):

Because **df** is the original dataframe and df("count") attempts to return column that is not in the original dataframe, Dataframes are immutable objects that can not be modified, you can only queue transformation that return new dataframes without modifying the original dataframe, thus groupby and agg does not modify the original **df** dataframe, but return new dataframes with the queued transformations (Spark is lazy).

**desc("count")** is a function that will look for a column with name "count" in the current dataframe, which is not the original **df**, but the one created by the **gorupby** + **agg** combo, which already have the "count" column.

BTW, you can re-use **df** in multiple transformations.